# Excepción PDO no detectada: SQLSTATE[HY000]: Error general: 2014 Cuando se ejecuta un Procedimiento Almacenado

Tags: php, mariadb, mysqlprocedure

Hola espero que me puedan ayudar con esto:

Estoy tratando de llamar un procedimiento almacenado con php

y al momento de llamar a la consulta me genera este error:

Excepción PDO no detectada: SQLSTATE[HY000]: Error general: 2014 No se pueden ejecutar consultas mientras otras consultas sin búfer están activas. Considere usar PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternativamente, si su código solo se ejecutará contra mysql, puede habilitar el almacenamiento en búfer de consultas configurando el atributo PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY.

```
 $query = 'Call procedure(1)';
 

 $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();

     $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     if ($stmt->rowCount()){
             $response = $stmt->fetchAll();
     } else{
             $response = false;
     }
```

en la llamada a la base de datos tengo unos atributos

```
 $dbConnection = new PDO($dsn, $userName, $password);
 $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
 $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
 $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
 $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
```

y este ultimó es que me informa del error

```
 $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

el problema el procedimiento almacenado está bien y si yo quito la captura del error pues se hace correctamente sin ningún contratiempo me trae la información y se hace todo de manera correcta no entiendo porque? `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` me arroja ese error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procedure`(IN Id_Cliente INT(11))
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM contactos
    WHERE IdC = Id_Cliente;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

PHP: 7.4.29
Mariadb 10.4.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve investigando un poco más

resulta que al finalizar la consulta del procedimiento

```
$query = 'Call procedure(1)';
 

 $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();

     $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     if ($stmt->rowCount()){
             $response = $stmt->fetchAll();
             $stmt->closeCursor();
     } else{
             $response = false;
     }
```

tenía que agregar el `closeCursor();` para pues de alguna forma limpiar mi cursor y que este no causara conflicto

respondí a si para si alguien llegara atener el problema pueda resolverlo también

Comment: es correcto tambien es bueno cerrrar las conexiones a las base de datos etc... todo lo que consuma recursos innecesarios ...